# how to add javascript functionality to a variable

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, parameters

Hello I am trying to add a string in Javascript like `.something(variable)` on variable x which is defined as

```
   var x = white.reference(action)
```

if another variable returns `false`

so in hindsight if `var y = false` then `.something(variable)` will be added to `var x` to look something like

```
    x = white.reference(action).something(variable)
```

I am not sure how to approach this method and problem

Comment: you mean wrappers ?

Comment: Yeah Im not sure with terminology of Javascript im sorry

Comment: or is it about chaining function ? what is `white.reference (action)` ?? is it a JS object with method ?

Comment: yes I am trying to do chaining method I am trying to add on a chaining object with a method if a separate variable is to return false

Comment: This is not a problem but a teaching! => https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: if a variable *is* `false` it cannot have a chaining method (since it is a primitive). Only objects can have methods.

Comment: so you mean to chain `white.reference(action)` with `.something(variable)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator can help.  An expression of the form...

```
(condition)? expressionA : expressionB;
```

will evaluate to the value of expressionA, if condition is true, or expressionB, if condition is false.  Applying that to the OP expressions...

```
let x = (y)? white.reference(action) : white.reference(action).something(variable);
```